# Angular2 form template variable gets updated after click function gets triggered

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

In Angular2 I have this code:

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(f)">
   <input type="checkbox" name="foo" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="onChange(f)"/>
</form>
```

The onChange function looks like this:

```
onChange(form):void{
 let val =  form.value.foo;
}
```

When the page loads, the checkbox is checked. When I uncheck it, the onChange function is called, but the form.value.foo is the stale value. It doesn't seem to update the form template variable before calling onChange function. I need that form variable to be updated to the latest DOM before the onChange function is called. Is there something I am missing? Is it always that angular2 first calls the onChange function before updating the template variable f that points to ngForm?

Here is my plunkr code: https://plnkr.co/edit/zUJmO3PTxsuJtxYikXKw?p=preview

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am using Angular2 version 2.0.1. I found this problem even with version 2.0.0 also.

Comment: I see. I guess you should report this as bug.

Comment: I added in my plunkr code as well. https://plnkr.co/edit/zUJmO3PTxsuJtxYikXKw?p=preview. Will report it.